# CSOM object not initialized

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I have code that gets group information from a SharePoint Online site using the CSOM API. I want to compare the id of a group with the ids of the associated groups of the web.

When the code runs in Azure (workerrole), I get an 'CheckUninitializedProperty' exception:

```
Error:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.CheckUninitializedProperty(String propName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Principal.get_Id()
```

The weird thing is that the code works when I run it in a console app on my laptop. (same site and same user credentials)

Here is the code:

```
private bool AdjustGroups(ClientContext targetCtx, Group group)
{
   targetCtx.Load(targetCtx.Web);
   targetCtx.Load(targetCtx.Web.AssociatedMemberGroup, i => i.Id, i => i.Title);
   targetCtx.Load(targetCtx.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup, i => i.Id, i => i.Title);
   targetCtx.Load(targetCtx.Web.AssociatedVisitorGroup, i => i.Id, i => i.Title);
   targetCtx.ExecuteQuery();

   // Any of the follwoing lines results in the error   
   LogMessage(string.Format("groupid is: {0}", targetCtx.Web.AssociatedVisitorGroup.Id));
   LogMessage(string.Format("groupid is: {0}", targetCtx.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Id));
   LogMessage(string.Format("groupid is: {0}", targetCtx.Web.AssociatedMemberGroup.Id));
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing on my Azure deployment?